# Get woocommerce sale price instead of regular price?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to grab the sale price of a woocommerce product and than display the price 20% off.

The code I have right now is sort of working. Its grabbing the "regular" price and displaying that as 20% off. But I would like it to grab the sale price.

How is this done in woocommerce?

Here is my PHP

```
<?php
if($product->product_type=='variable') {
    global $product;
    $sales_price = esc_attr( $product->get_display_price() );
    $discount = 20;
    $currency = esc_attr( get_woocommerce_currency() );
    $new_price = ($sales_price * $discount) / 20;

    echo 'Get this product for '.$new_price.$currency.' with (Promo code)';
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to use [`$sales_price = esc_attr( $product->get_sale_price() );`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_is_on_sale)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get sale price something like this `$_product->get_sale_price();` instead of `esc_attr( $product->get_display_price()`